# In subnetting, is a router interface considered a 'host'?

Tags: subnet

When calculating the subnets in VLSM, you generally need to specify the number of hosts in a subnet. Should I consider a router's interface a host as well?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the answer is yes, because a router needs an IP address assigned to it (so that other devices can communicate with other networks through default gateway).

Comment: Yes. Some people always assign the first usable host address to the router interface, some people always assign the last usable host address to the router interface, and some people randomly assign a usable host address to the router interface. It really does not matter which usable host address you assign to the router interface, but a best practice to be consistent in your router interface address assignment. On a LAN, every interface (PC, printer, router, etc.) is assigned a unique usable host address.

Answer (score 2):

The *"hosts"* in a subnet calculation is shorthand for the *"available host addresses"* to distinguish from the total number of ip-addresses in a range.

The is primarily relevant when you have small subnets when that can become a significant difference, as you can effectively "loose" up to 50% of the total number of IP-addresses in a range to broadcast addresses and network ID's.

It is up to you to decide to which devices you assign those available host addresses and if you assign one to a router it can't be assigned to a laptop, server or your fridge. So yes, the ip-address for your router counts as a host.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the router counts as host.

Answer (score 0):

In a local area network if you provide an IP address to the router. it means you can not provide that IP address to other devices in the same network it means it is also a valid host in the network.
Yes, the IP address for your router count as a host.